# Ubuntu 14.04 boot full and update keeps installing older kernels

Tags: package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

I got a security update in Ubuntu 14.04, but at the time of installation it says your disk is full. See the result of`df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            980M  4.0K  980M   1% /dev
tmpfs           198M  1.2M  197M   1% /run
/dev/sda6        14G   11G  2.0G  85% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            990M   20M  971M   2% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda11       59G  8.4G   48G  16% /home
```

and `df -i`

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            214806    544  214262    1% /dev
tmpfs           219956    568  219388    1% /run
/dev/sda6       915712 915645      67  100% /
none            219956      2  219954    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            219956      3  219953    1% /run/lock
none            219956     17  219939    1% /run/shm
none            219956     34  219922    1% /run/user
/dev/sda11     3907008 297045 3609963    8% /home
```

So, I removed some of the older Ubuntu kernels forcefully as the update was not allowing me to remove it normally by using `sudo dpkg --force-all -P linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic`

But, to complete the update when I am trying to run the command `sudo apt-get install -f` it is installing the same older kernels and giving the same memory error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm3.6 libntdb1 linux-headers-3.19.0-25 linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-34 linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
  python-ntdb tex-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-vivid-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/32.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 72.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 896123 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic (3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/lib/raid6/raid6_pq.ko.dpkg-new' (while processing './lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/lib/raid6/raid6_pq.ko'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic_3.19.0-61.69~14.04.1_i386.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic (3.19.0-61.69~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic_3.19.0-61.69~14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/lib/modules/3.19.0-61-generic/kernel/net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6t_ipv6header.ko.dpkg-new' (while processing './lib/modules/3.19.0-61-generic/kernel/net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6t_ipv6header.ko'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-61-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-61-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-61-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-61-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic_3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic_3.19.0-61.69~14.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and if I am trying to install any random software then too it is giving this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-61-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic but it is not going to be installed
 python-distutils-extra : Depends: intltool but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can anybody help me in rectifying this?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: yes I ran that also

Comment: it is giving the same unmet dependencies error, the same thing i have posted in last output.

Comment: Try `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: @George: for everything it is giving same unmet dependencies error

Comment: please try: `sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential`, then try again

Comment: Please run these in sequence: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get -f install`..., pls run one after the other

Comment: thank you so much..now everything is working...but can you explain what is the problem...and why earlir it was not working.Also how can i remove old kernels? @george

Comment: Doing `sudo apt-get autoremove` should get rid of the extra luggage, will be dropping an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: It is best to always update and upgrade a system before any install, I usually do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before any install to prevent broken package issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this to add any build dependcies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential
```

Source: [man apt-get]

> build-dep:
>
> build-dep causes apt-get to install/remove packages in an attempt to satisfy the build dependencies for a
>                  source package. By default the dependencies are satisfied to build the package natively. If desired a
>                  host-architecture can be specified with the --host-architecture option instead.

Comment: sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential this resolves the problem. because all 3 commands i have tried earlier.

Comment: did the `autoremove` get rid of extra luggae?

Comment: Yes! did that :)